# Normalized sigmoid loss function for boosting?

Tags: boosting, loss-functions

It seems non-convexity of loss function is not such a problem for [boosting with a normalized sigmoid loss function](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.19.2603&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Do you know any further work showing better results with this kind of boosting than [Adaboost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) (exponential loss function)?

Here are the graphs of different loss functions adapted from the graphs shown in [*A note on margin-based loss functions in classification*](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?cluster=5316650282096740506&hl=fr&as_sdt=0,5&as_vis=1) by Yi Lin:
[image]

---

Edit: The first Google Scholar link now points to: *Boosting algorithms as gradient descent in function space* by Llew Mason, Jonathan Baxter, Peter Bartlett, and Marcus Frean (1999).

Comment: I currently have exactly the same question. Did you get any clue on this?

Comment: Also the google scholar link is broken, what were you linking to?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the reference anymore. I would not have expect Google Scholar to break links.

Comment: The link is not broken anymore.

Comment: You might look at this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.06951.pdf He, Z., Lin, D., Lau, T., & Wu, M. (2019). Gradient Boosting Machine: A Survey. arXiv preprint arXiv:1908.06951.